# REST api one-to-many deep relation

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I have such a models on a site: `Organization`, `Client` and `Comment` .

A `Organization` can have many `Clients`, a `Client` belongs to `Organization` , a `Client` can have many `Comments`, a `Comment` belongs to one `Client`.

Obviously, `Client` is not a first-class resource, so i create update and get it through an `Organization` like:

`POST/organizations/:org_id/clients` - create a Client
`PUT/organizations/:org_id/clients/:client_id` - update a Client,
and so on

But what my route should be when i want to add a `Comment` to a `Client` ?

Should it be

`POST/organizations/:org_id/clients/:client_id/comments`

or

`POST/clients/:client_id/comments`

or

`POST/comments`

Answer (score 0):

In many cases REST interface mimics the data structure.

since you have comments that belong to a client, then most probably your internal data representation is a table, where primary key is comment id and foreign key is client id. it has nothing to do with client belonging to a particular organization. hence

```
POST/clients/:client_id/comments
```

If later you would want to edit a comment that would be

```
PUT/clients/:client_id/comments/:comment_id
```

In theory, you may even move the client_id to be part of the post parameters, but in this case you will be loosing proper way to list all the comments for given customer.